# After loading webarchiev into WebView app crashes

Tags: android, webview, webarchive

After trying to load WebArchievs for some sites I get this error.

```
06-12 11:03:36.604    6257-6257/<packageName> D/﹕ Page started file:///data/data/<packageName>/files/savedData3.mht
06-12 11:03:36.644    6257-6281/<packageName> V/RenderScript﹕ Application requested CPU execution
06-12 11:03:36.649    6257-6281/<packageName> V/RenderScript﹕ 0xb8ec6f88 Launching thread(s), CPUs 2
06-12 11:03:36.662    6257-6332/<packageName> E/chromium﹕ ### WebView Version 43.0.2357.121 (code 2357121)
06-12 11:03:36.662    6257-6332/<packageName> A/libc﹕ Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x4 in tid 6332 (Thread-36203)
```

Saving WebArchiev:

```
getWebView().saveWebArchive(<pathToFile>);
```

Loading WebArchiv:

```
getWebView().loadUrl(<pathToFile>);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13445760/603270

Comment: @ shkschneider, it is not an answer on my question. My method displays content well. But loading  saved webarchievs for some page crashes the app. And if you will read the answer, in your link, more attentively, you will see, that gregko recommends to use webView.loadUrl("file:///my_dir/mySavedWebPage.mht") since Kitkat.

Comment: Right, sorry. Have you tried loading another MHT file? Maybe its content provokes the crash (SIGSEGV btw), which should indeed not happen...

Comment: @shkschneider, yes i tried, and many pages are loaded without crash. But pages and .mht for them changes dynamicly in app, and I need a way to check .mht content to prevent crash. Maybe i need some spec configuration for webview.

Comment: Oh, good question then. Will be hard to catch since it is not a Java exception but rather a native crash at system-low-level (SIGSEGV)... Don't know sorry. Upvoted.

Comment: Added issue report to https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list, link to report https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=499736&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Week%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified