# How to cache a webpage for use in my android app even when offline

Tags: android, caching

I am making an Android app for a web page using Android Studio, but i want the app to be able to cache the last web page that was viewed when there was internet connection so that on reopening the app, that web page would be the first page to be seen, even when the user is offline, just like the twitter app, and then on a button click the user can get updates from the web page.

Comment: Are you using a webview?

Comment: @Double_M welcome to stack overflow. Please read the how to ask session: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Can you post your code?

Comment: See the following post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12872043/android-webview-display-webarchive

Comment: So sorry guys, I haven't been online for certain reasons.   But i do appreciate the replies and assistant.

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen the `WebView.saveWebArchive()` method? I think that's what you're looking for. Have a look at the following post for more info: [Android WebView -> Display WebArchive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12872043/android-webview-display-webarchive)